# How can I stop this ProgressBar from being scrolled along with the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to stop this `ProgressBar` from being scrolled up and down along with the toolbars? Right now I have two toolbars that are supposed to be scrolled up and down when there are items in a `RecyclerView`, the problem is that the scrolling behaviour is affecting the layout below the toolbar when there aren't any results to show. Take a look:

[image: Gif showing behaviour]

Needless to say, the progressbar shouldn't be scrolled under any circumstances. This are the layouts:

`activity_base.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:minHeight="64dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:minHeight="64dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_sites"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_sort_field"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_sort_order"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/activity_masterdetail"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_search_tint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:background="#88000000"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layerType="hardware"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <org.cryse.widget.persistentsearch.PersistentSearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:persistentSV_logoString="@string/app_name"
            app:persistentSV_searchTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            app:persistentSV_editTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            app:persistentSV_editHintText="Search"
            app:persistentSV_editHintTextColor="?android:textColorHint"
            app:persistentSV_displayMode="toolbar"
            app:persistentSV_homeButtonMode="burger"
            app:persistentSV_searchCardElevation="2dp"
            app:persistentSV_customToolbarHeight="64dp"
            app:layout_behavior=".ScrollingSearchViewBehavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The include `<include layout="@layout/activity_masterdetail"/>` is a ref that points to `activity_fragment.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

The `fragment_list.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <!-- include pogress bar-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        layout="@layout/progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `progress_bar` is just your regular, run of the mill progressbar for now:

```
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.wrap_content.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

As you can see other than the SearchView the layout is very standard so I don't know why this issue is happening. I've found that removing the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `activity_fragment.xml` stops the issue from happening but then the `RecyclerView` isn't aligned with the toolbar and the results appear all over the screen, covering the toolbar and all. That's certainly not what I want to happen.

Marking the `RecyclerView`'s visibility as 'gone' also stops the scrolling of the `ProgressBar` but the same it's not being centralized, meaning that the issue is still there is just that I can't scroll the screen. Setting the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute in almost every container also didn't work. I've tried tweaking almost all layout attributes that I could think of with no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried including it outside of the `CoordinatorLayout` or including the progress bar outside of it's `RelativeLayout` ? It shouldn't be at the same depth as the `RecyclerView` if you wish to avoid scrolling (in other words, being 'on top' of the recyclerView)

Comment: I would say, that it should be in Activity and from fragment you could make it possible to call using callback's of Activity

Comment: @Shark I've thought about it but the thing is I want it to be centralized within the fragment's layout because at some resolutions this would be a two pane layout and there would be other progressbar associated with (and centralized within) the other pane. Like two-pane Gmail app does on tablets.

Comment: Including the progressbar at the fragment's root layout would do it, no? Somehow it really needs to be 'above' (Z-axis wise) the recyclerview to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Shark you mean in activity_fragment.xml? Well, right now it is above the recyclerview right where it is but for some reason the layout has some empty space below the bottom of the screen that you can scroll... I have tried applying wrap_content where relevant but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: It is not above, it's on the exactly same depth as RecyclerView. Either put the recyclerview one depth below it (by wrapping it in a Layout of it's own) or put the progress bar one depth above the recyclerview. Example: `<Layout ... <Layout ... <Layout><TextView text2></Layout><TextView text1></Layout></Layout>` - text2 is on depth `3` while text1 is on depth `2`. Thus, text2 is above text1. So either wrap the RecyclerView or the ProgressBar in a layout of it's own with `match_parent` for both. It should work fine.

Comment: @Shark I did what you suggest but it keeps behaving the same way. I tried both with match_parent and wrap_content: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db925f5e123fa7bb7c6d9f7c1a0722f5

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'll have to post an answer to my own question, it's more of a workaround really but it works. I'll be waiting for an "actual" answer and mark it as such whenever it's posted.

What you have to do is remove the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute from `activity_fragment.xml` and add it programatically after the `ProgressBar` has been hidden away with `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. You also have to make sure that it is removed whenever you're going to show the `ProgressBar` again. This usually can be done in Asynctask's `onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` methods. To do this you need to keep a reference to the `@+id/fragment_list` fragment. Here is the code:

```
View parent;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // keeping a reference to the @+id/fragment_list fragment
    parent = container;
    // other code
    task = new SearchResultsTask();
    task.execute();
    return view;
}
```

And on `SearchResultsTask` `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    adapter.adds(s);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    // adding the behaviour programatically
    params.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior());
    parent.requestLayout();

    rvList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    // removing the behaviour
    params.setBehavior(null);
    parent.requestLayout();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```